# Слитное или раздельное написание частицы НЕ с существительными?

Tags: частица-не

Как написать частицу "не" в данном контексте: "Возможно использование (не)глаголов в “общепринятых” случаях" - слитно или раздельно? Каким правилом русского языка мы должны пользоваться в данном случае?

Answer (score 1):

ПРАВИЛО

Приставка НЕ со слитным написанием  входит в состав ограниченного количества слов, а именно: 
А) качественных прилагательных: далёкий – недалёкий; 
Б) образованных от них наречий на О/Е: ясно – неясно; 
В) существительных с абстрактным значением: удача – неудача; 
Г) отрицательных и неопределенных  местоимений и наречий: где – негде, нигде;  .

В остальных случаях используется отрицательная частица НЕ с раздельным написанием:
это глаголы и деепричастия, слова категории состояния, а также числительные, местоимения  и наречия.  Слитное написание НЕ  для этой категории слов является исключительным.

РЕШЕНИЕ

Слова "неглагол", образованного о слова "глагол" префиксальным способом, не существует в языке, его вы не найдете в словаре. Дело в том, что здесь отсутствует какой-либо утвердительный смысл, только отрицание, мы не можем дать определения этому слову.

Comment: Смысл-то как раз есть (если я правильно его поняла)- слова других частей речи, кроме глаголов. И раздельное написание в таком случае было бы неверным. Но и слитно написать нельзя, так как нет такого слова "неглагол". Остается правильно построить фразу. Откорректировать не могу, так как не очень понимаю, что Вы имеете в виду под словом "неглагол": все остальные части речи или все остальные самостоятельные части речи...

Comment: Имеются в виду другие части речи, кроме глаголов.
Переделать просто: "Использование частей речи, отличных от глаголов, возможно лишь в общепринятых случаях". Но тут именно идёт борьба за лаконичность.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с Ларф. Трудно понять, что имеется в виду под словом "неглагол".А вот собственно правило.http:[Грамма.ру](//www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.52)

Comment: Кстати, если опираясь на эти правила, сложно сделать какой-то вывод. Это случай хоть как-то подпадает только под третий пункт и под второе примечание. И оба они говорят о слитном написании.

Comment: Нужно оставить фразу «Использование частей речи, отличных от глаголов, возможно только в общепринятых случаях», как единственно корректную, так как  написание «не глаголы»   в русской орфографии не допускается. По поводу ПРАВИЛА для слов «неспециалист, нелитератор" и др.  Эти слова могут писаться с НЕ слитно,  приобретая  утвердительный смысл, но он обязательно связан с ПРОТИВОПОСТАВЛЕНИЕМ  ЛИЦ по какому-либо признаку: литераторы и нелитераторы, специалисты и неспециалисты. Правило не относится К ПРОТИВОПОСТАВЛЕНИЮ ПРЕДМЕТОВ: книги и не книги, глаголы и не глаголы.